# the function of this command : exec rake assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Anyone knows what is this command used for in ruby on rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hello please see follwing links :

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

and for Heroku :

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline